# If you aren't "immune", could you be "mune"?

Tags: etymology, negation, historical-change

In English, "immune", meaning "invulnerable", seems to be the antithesis of a hypothetical word "mune", which would logically mean "vulnerable".

Is there, or has there ever been a word "mune", to which "immune" would be the antithesis?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. The issue here is that the medical sense is based on a transfer from finance/taxation:

[immune](https://www.etymonline.com/word/immune):

mid-15c., "free, exempt" (from taxes, tithes, sin, etc.), from Latin *immunis* "exempt from public service, untaxed; unburdened, not tributary," literally ""not paying a share," from assimilated form of *in-* "not, opposite of" (see *in-* (1)) + *munis* "performing services" (compare *municipal*), from PIE **moi-n-es-*, suffixed form of root **mei-* (1) "to change, go, move." **Specific modern medical sense of "exempt (from a disease)," typically because of inoculation, is from 1881, a back-formation from *immunity***. *Immune system* attested by 1917.

So it's the *muni* part from *municipal* that you'd be talking about. This part occurs as a component part in some words (*munificent*, *municipality*), but **does not exist as an independent word in the English language**. It's not the same as *munition*, which is derived from a different Latin root.

Comment: But that apparently never entered English as such – which is what OP is asking about. Also, the Etymon material should have been provided with the question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, that would have been couth.